# How many max healers on queen will be enough?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am doing queen walk these days. I have level 15 queen. I put three healers on her and they are enough if not faced by xbows. Whenever both xbows or even one of them beasts starts shooting the queen she dies easily. My question is if I use 7 or 8 healers, will that provide enough heal to her if faced by both xbows?

Answer (score 2):

using more than 4 Healers will decrease the amount heal given to the heroes...So you should not use more than 4 or 5 healers.

When targeted by XBows, use rage spell on the healers to increase the healing..The point defences like cannon,archer tower and xbows are the main enemies of the Queen Walk..So you have to take them out quickly.

Good luck